# Facebook PHP SDK - Logged in/Not Logged in/Connected to App Status

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

I currently have a Javascript that enables me to identify the three states of the user visiting my site:-

1. Not logged in to Facebook
2. Logged in to Facebook but not connected to my app
3. Logged in to Facebook and connected to my app

This is great and works wonderfully, except that I have three different bits of content to be displayed for the three types of status and currently we load all three states into the DOM and use jQuery to display the correct version as soon as the status of the user is understood.

Loading three different content types only to ever display one is not a very good way of doing things.  I have two options:-

1. Use the Facebook SDK to get the same information server side
2. Use AJAX to load the correct content

So, my question: Is it possible to determine the three states that I've listed above using the Facebook PHP SDK?

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            FB.api('/me', {accessToken: response.authResponse.accessToken}, function(user) {
               //connected to the app
            });
        } else {
            if (response.status == "not_authorized") {
               // logged in but not connected
            } else {
               // not connected to Facebook
            }
        }
    });
```

Any help on this much appreciated because I'm a bit stumped after many hours of trying.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the session variables.

I seem to remember that if the user is logged in but hasn't authorized your app that the access token will be your app's access token instead of a user access token.

Also take a look at the example from Facebook's PHP SDK on [how to use it along with the JS SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/with_js_sdk.php) making sure you have `cookie:true` set for the JS SDK.